# Doubt about the proof of Bernoulli's law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Bernoulli's weak law says:

> If $X_1,X_2, ... , X_n, ... $ are independent random variables and they have the same Bernoulli's distribution of parameter p, then: $\frac{S_n}{n} \longrightarrow^{P} p$

Well the proof starts with $\operatorname{Var}(S_n) = npq$ and $E(S_n) = np$ and using that convergence on media-p implies convergence on probability, so:

$E(\frac{S_n}{n} - p)^2 = E(\frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{n})^2 = \frac{Var(S_n)}{n^2} = \frac{pq}{n}$

And after this my proof says that as $\frac{S_n}{n} \longrightarrow^{m-2} p$ but I don't know why can I affirm that $\frac{pq}{n} \longrightarrow 0$.

Comment: You have mixed up the formulas for $\operatorname{Var}(S_n)$ and $E(S_n)$. What 
 does "convergence on media-p" mean?

Comment: Convergence on media-p means that $E(X_n - X)^p \longrightarrow 0$

Comment: p and q are fixed and $n \to \infty$, so $pq/n \to 0$.

Comment: Ah okey, that was the point that I left

Comment: There is no telling what $m$ or $q$ means, but your expressions for mean and variance of $S_n$ look incorrect, perhaps they are swapped.  Of course there is no telling what $S_n$ means, either, but I assume that is the sum of the first $n$ random variables.

Comment: $m, q \in \mathbb{N}$ and yes, they are swapped (I will correct this right now) and of course $S_n$ is the sum of the first n random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Chebyshev inequality: define
$$
V_n = \frac{S_n}{n}, EV_n = p, Var V_n = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}
$$
Hence,
$$
P(|V_n - p|> \varepsilon)< \frac{Var V_n}{\varepsilon^2} = \frac{p(1-p)}{n \varepsilon^2}\to_n 0
$$
Hence $V_n \to p$ in probability. For convergence in law ($\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$,
$$
P(|\frac{S_n}{n} - p|> \varepsilon) = 1-P\bigg(-\frac{\varepsilon \sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \leq \frac{S_n - np}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \leq\frac{\varepsilon n}{\sigma}\bigg) \\\approx1-\Phi(\frac{\varepsilon \sqrt{n}}{\sigma})+ \Phi(-\frac{\varepsilon \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}) \to_n 0
$$

Comment: Well this is another way of proving it, but my doubt was with the other way of proof by the implication of convergence in media-p implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Do you mean convergence almost surely?

Comment: No, convergence in media-p implies convergence in probability

Comment: I added the proof for convergence in law, but I'm not sure that's what you wanted though